# How to get the oddly indexed elements in a list in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to get the oddly indexed elements in a list? I am thinking of Select, but did not find anything returning an element's position, especially considering there are repetitive elements in the list.

Also in general, how to select those elements whose indices satisfy some certain conditions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a lot of ways, here are some of them:

```
In[2]:= a = Range[10];le = Length@a;

In[3]:= Table[a[[i]], {i, 1, le, 2}]

In[5]:= Pick[a, Table[Mod[i, 2], {i, 1, le}], 1]

In[6]:= a[[1 ;; le ;; 2]]
```

In general, with Pick[] (as an example) you can model any conceivable index mask.

Comment: Supplying the length in the `Span` (`1;;le;;2`) is not required. By default, the second term is the end of the list. So, `1;;;;2` works exactly the same.

Comment: @rcollyer you are right! See also Michael's answer, he uses -1 instead of Length[ ], which also can be avoided.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a few more in addition to [@belisarius's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813111/how-to-get-the-oddly-indexed-elements-in-a-list-in-mathematica/4813172#4813172), which don't require computing `Length[lis]`:

```
Take[lis, {1, -1, 2}]

lis[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]
```

You can often use `-1` to represent the "last" position.

Comment: A question: AFAIK Length[ ] is not computing (its timing is nil). Am I correct?

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the terse form of `Span` has been omitted from the answers.

```
Range[20][[;;;;2]]
```

```
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}
```

[Quoting the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html):

```
;;;;k 
from the beginning to the end in steps of k.
```